# Adding website action link to android native share widget?

Tags: javascript, android

Is there a way to add a website action link to native share widget in Android without developing an app as shown below?

Android Share Action Item:

[image]

Simply need user to capture the data (url) from any app on android and post it to my url for processing without needing a new app to do this?